# Three.js object3D.toJSON submitted parameters

Tags: json, three.js, export

Why are there only material and geometry in the file created by toJSON() ?
Why do I have to add other object's parameters(position, rotation,etc.) manually?

Answer (score 1):

In the source, it does seem to keep that info. It keeps the Matrix, but I'm not sure if that'll work out of the box without some operation, like updating the matrix? I dont know enough in that area.

But another alternative I saw in the source is to stash that info into "userData", and then retrieve it on the other end, because that does get passed along in the source.

If no one comes along to give better advice than I am capable of, you should add this as a request/issue ticket on github. It's possible that it's an outstanding/ new issue.